# Format issue with Windows Edge display of PDF files

Tags: windows, pdf, microsoft-edge

When I download a PDF file using Windows 11, Edge, it displays as a tab in the browser. But when I "save as" of the Edge reader options, it displays the PDF in a separate window as shown in the image below. I can pin this window to the status bar, and it indicates it as being an Edge application, but if I close that window and then try to reopen it as a separate window, it always displays in a tab of the full-blown browser. How do I get a saved PDF file to open in that same dedicated window? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The window in your screenshot does not look like a Microsoft Edge feature, and the expected behavior is to open a PDF in a full-blown browser window. I have tried multiple times but I just failed to replicate the same window as yours.

But there's another solution to open a PDF in a dedicated window, and you'll still be able to use all the features in Microsoft Edge PDF viewer. That is, **open PDFs in app mode**.

1. After you save the PDF file, open the Command Prompt and enter: `start msedge --app=C:\path\to\your\file.pdf`. You shall be able to have a dedicated PDF window after that.
2. Pin the new window to taskbar.
3. Right click on the newly-pinned shortcut --> right click on Microsoft Edge --> select Properties[image]
4. In the **Target** box, add `--app=C:\path\to\your\file.pdf`. Now your **Target** box should look like: `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --app=C:\path\to\your\file.pdf`.
5. Now you can open the PDF in a dedicated window from the taskbar shortcut. You can also customize the icon and display name, of course.